# How to run multiple promises [type script targeting es5]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I want to run multiple methods returning promises. I know I can do it like a daisy chain. But are there any ways I will be able to run them with something similar to Promise.All.
myFunction().then(
myFunction2().then(
myFunction3().then(
//run main logic here
)
)
);
Promise.All for ES6 is not an option for me.

Comment: `Promise.all` will wait in parallel, while a daisy chain of `f1.then(f2).then(f3) /* ... */` will be sequential. Which one do you want?

Comment: Also, if you have promises in ES5, you must have some library that implements them. Check if that library doesn't already provide a `Promise.all` equivalent or other functionality for conveniently waiting until promises resolve in certain way.

Comment: The order is not important to me.

Comment: Which library do you use to implement promises in ES5?